# what is the use of get in "Class { get isFunction(){ } }"?

Tags: javascript, meteor

having javascript class :

```
export class PartyDetails extends MeteorComponent {
    constructor(params:RouteParams) {
        super();
    }
    get isOwner(): boolean {
        if (this.party && this.user) {
            return this.user._id === this.party.owner;
        }    
        return false;
    }    
}
```

What is the purpose of the `get` for `get isOwner()`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Defining_getters_and_setters

Answer (score 0):

Get is part of the syntax to create a property.  Have a look at the [documentation for properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Property_definitions).